# How to create nested json with laravel or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, nested

I need to have something like this:

```
  "results":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "date":{  
        "date":"2015-04-1 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type":3,
        "timezone":"America\/Denver"
     }
  },
```

query:

```
$find = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT created_at as date, 'America/Denver' as timezone, 3 as timezone_type FROM table"));
return Response::json($find);
```

How to create date within date with mysql/Laravel? I tried to use array_merge but date will be appended at the bottom instead of make itself nested.

Comment: Show us how your table in mysql looks like and the code that you use to get the array from datatabase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code to the code below:

```
        $tableIds = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id FROM table"));
        $jsonResult = array();

        for($i = 0;$i < count($tableIds);$i++)
        {
            $jsonResult[$i]["id"] = $tableIds[$i]->id;
            $id = $tableIds[$i]->id;
            $jsonResult[$i]["date"] = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT created_at as date, 'America/Denver' as timezone, 3 as timezone_type  FROM table WHERE id = $id"));
        }

        return Response::json(array(
                    'error'     =>  false,
                    'stores'    =>  $jsonResult),
                    200
            );
```

Comment: You could use a recursive function that iterates through each level, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Great coding but faced problem, I am creating nested json response in laravel. I am taking three tables as category_type={category_type_id,category_name};
main_category={main_category_id,category_type_id,main_category_name}
sub_category={sub_category_id,category_type_id,main_category_id,sub_category_name} and I am using  coding and getting json but I want to nested third table in second plZ changes in coding I already nested second in first now I want nested third table in second